# ST-link doesnt run the MCU after programming and reset in KEIL 5.33

Tags: stm32, keil

I have updated my KEIL from 5.15 to 5.33. In KEIL 5.15 I set Reset and Run option in Flash->Configure Flash Tools->Debug( Selecting St-link) Settings->flash download and after programming my MCU start working. However, after updating KEIL to 5.33 it just program my MCU and I should power off/on my MCU to start working.
I need to know what it the problem with this new version of KEIL.

Comment: Have you asked Keil? Since it's their compiler you bought with support.

Comment: There are two types of reset, soft and NRST.  Do you have NRST connected?  Are you using a true ST-link or one of the little dongles where the reset pin is not actually functional? You may need configuration for soft reset.

Comment: Thank you very much for your both comments. Yes, I have connected NRST pin. Could you let me know how to do soft reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please uncheck Enable in Pack Tab